# How do I set the default select value on an array of objects?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a select that binds to a collection of objects. I wanted to add a default value "Please select" but I can't seem to get it to select the item by default:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="ingredient.definition" class="form-select" name="ingredient{{ i }}">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please select</option>
    <option *ngFor="let definition of definitions" [ngValue]="definition" [disabled]="disableOption(definition)">{{ definition.name }}</option>
</select>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary d-block" [disabled]="disableAdd()" (click)="addIngredient()">Add ingredient</button>
```

Here is my definition interface:

```
export interface Definition {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  measurement: string;
  unit: string;
  measurementToUnit: number;
  unitPrice: number;
}
```

and my ingredient interface:

```
import { Definition } from './definition';

export interface Ingredient {
  quantity: number;
  definition: Definition;
}
```

The select is dynamically added, so upon adding the select I execute the following to create an empty object:

```
addIngredient(): void {
    let ingredient: Ingredient = {
      quantity: 0,
      definition: {} as Definition
    }
    this.model.ingredients.push(ingredient);
}
```

Since the definition object on my property is empty, I was hoping the select would automatically highlight the empty default option, however this isn't the case:

[image]

I've also tried creating a dummy `definition` object with the name "Please select" and adding that to the `definitions` collection, however that doesn't seem to work either.

Does anyone know the correct way to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: assign ingredient.definition = ""; that should solve your problem in your component

Comment: try `[value]="null" disabled hidden` (or `[ngValue]="{}" disabled hidden`. NOTE: **remove** the "selected" of your option. You're using [(ngModel)], so you should only "play" with the variable

Answer (score 1):

I came across such scenarios a couple of times as this issue arises due to indexing of options dynamically populating.

Instead of ngModel and ngValue, try using formControl and patchvalue.

TS:

```
public defaultSelectName: string = 'someOption';

public optionsForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    options: new FormControl(null, {validators: Validators.nullValidator})
});

public setDefaultOption(): void {
    const matchedIndex= this.definitions.findIndex(definition => definition.name === defaultSelectName);
    if (matchedIndex) {
        this.optionsForm.get('options')!.patchValue(this. definitions[matchedIndex].name)
    }
}
```

by doing so, you're explicitly setting the default selected value along with its index.

Answer (score 0):

so following on from @Eliseo's suggestion, I managed to get it to work with:

```
<option [value]="{}" disabled>Please select</option>
```

Thanks so much